# Angular 2 - Jasmine Test - Open Modal On Page Load

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a modal which is opened as soon as the user selects the menu option for the page.  Isue i'm having is that i have no idea on how to get it to call my function call in my `ngOnInit`

**test.component.ts**

```
constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.openTestModal();
}

openTestModal() {
    this.dialog.open(TestModalComponent, {
        disableClose: true,
        width: '600px'
    });
}
```

I have imported my model component and tried:

**change-password.component.spec.ts**

```
import { TestModalComponent } from '../test-modal/test-modal.component';
    spyOn(component, 'openTestModal');
    spyOn(component, 'ngOnInit').and.callThrough();

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

**Error**

> No component factory found for TestComponent. Did you add it to
>   @NgModule.entryComponents?

but its already in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this add your TestComponent to a module at end of your test with entryComponents.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    TestComponent,
  ],
})
class TestModule {}
```

and add TestModule to the testBed imports.